# Protect a Web App from Access in Azure

Tags: azure, asmx

I have a web app running a old ASMX service that I want to limit access to for only other apps and services within my azure environment.

Is there any easy and cheap way to do this?

App Service Environments seems like it does this, but they seem rather expensive for this small purpose. I would be cheaper with a VM that I can configure the firewall on.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the IP-Ranges you can use web.config file in root of your app:

```
<security>
    <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">    <!-- this line blocks everybody, except those listed below -->                
        <clear/> <!-- removes all upstream restrictions -->
        <add ipAddress="127.0.0.1" allowed="true"/>    <!-- allow requests from the local machine -->
        <add ipAddress="81.116.19.53" allowed="true"/>   <!-- allow the specific IP of 81.116.19.53  -->                
        </ipSecurity>
</security>
```

Comment: Then a followup question, is there a internal IP in Azure that is used when one service uses another. If so how can I get it. Otherwise I guess checking the IP of the hostname is the way to go? Are they guaranteed to be the same over the years?

Comment: Don't know about such a list. The IP of the host can change but never happened to me.